# Tesseract not working when called from java application on redhat 6.2 box

Tags: java, redhat, tesseract, rhel6

I have a custom script which converts jpg to txt using tessaract 3.01. When i execute the script from command line the conversion works fine but when the same script is executed from a java application running on tomcat, it seems the application cannot find tesseract. This issue is happening on my redhat 6.2 box but not on my ubuntu 12.04 box.

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
SOURCE=$1 
TARGET=/tmp/ocrOutput 
echo "Starting tesseract" 
tesseract $SOURCE $TARGET -l eng 
echo " Finished"
```

Can someone please advice?

Comment: show the problematic code.

Comment: There could be many differences between RH and Ubuntu, including SELinux settings. Check the web server logs under /var/log and possibly the security logs there as well. Something there should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy                                                        #!/bin/sh
SOURCE=$1
TARGET=/tmp/ocrOutput
echo "Starting tesseract"
tesseract $SOURCE $TARGET -l eng
echo " Finished"

Comment: @rand'Chris SElinux is disabled and nothing in the webserver log as well

Answer (score 0):

The informations given are very minimal, but I guess it is a path problem. Try to use the full path when calling tesseract.